# How to see differences of Power BI files in git repo from bitbucket?

Tags: powerbi, bitbucket, git-diff

I store .pbix file in my git repository in Bitbucket. But when I change this file, I cannot see any differences in my PR.
[image]

Is there any plugins or git settings for that?

Answer (score 0):

No, `.pbix` files are binary (they actually are `.zip` files - rename one and open it) and you can't visualize the differences between binary files. Even if you extract the contents, there are still some binary files there (along with some XML files), so it is not possible either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good solution to this yet, at least not that I'm aware of.

What I do is use [Power BI Helper](https://radacad.com/power-bi-helper) to extract the M code for queries and DAX measures and then do version control on that.